# Reorganize a pandas dataframe based on columns values

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe that looks like this:

[image]

How do I convert it to this:

[image]

Comment: It does not. I want and exact replacement. The resulting table should have 5 lesser rows. Pivot does convert into two columns but existing 9 rows remain.

Comment: No images, refer to the guidelines here https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: whats the result of the Pivot, in your attempt? please share

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said that the number of x and y are same,

```py
'''
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'category' : ['x'] * 5 + ['y'] * 5,
    'values' : [i for i in range(1, 11)]
})
'''

category_dic = {'x' : [], 'y' : []}

for row in range(len(df)):
    category_dic[df.loc[row, 'category']].append(df.loc[row, 'values'])

df_1 = pd.DataFrame(category_dic)
```

Output :

```
>>> df_1
   x   y
0  1   6
1  2   7
2  3   8
3  4   9
4  5  10
```

※ Edit version(not using globals)

Comment: x and y are same in number. But I do want to avoid defining globals. Your output is exactly what I want, yet is there no other (pandas) way of solving this?